# Make an IBAction run 10 seconds after the click of a button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibaction

I have an `IBAction` linked to a button. When the button is clicked, a .wav file gets played.
How can I make the `IBAction` run 10 seconds after the click of the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [performSelector: withObject: afterDelay](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myFunc) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
```

Place this in the IBAction call that is called when your button is pressed, `myFunc` will be called 10 seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dispatch_after` to defer code execution:

```
- (IBAction) onAction: (id)sender
{
    double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        // do delayed work here
    });
}
```